# Makefile: "No rule to make ... needed by 'all'" despite all files being there

Tags: c, linux, makefile, mips, gnu-make

I'm having this weird problem with this makefile. Despite having all the required .c files, the compiling process stops at the first instruction, with this error.

`make: *** No rule to make target 'printerTest.umps', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

This exact code with the same exact files works in Debian Linux, though in Manjaro Arch Linux it return the error shown above.

Here's the makefile.

```
ifneq ($(wildcard /usr/bin/umps3),)
    UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX = /usr
    LIBDIR = $(UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/umps3
else
    UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX = /usr/local
    LIBDIR = $(UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX)/lib/umps3
endif

INCDIR = $(UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX)/include/umps3/umps
SUPDIR = $(UMPS3_DIR_PREFIX)/share/umps3

TDEFS = h/print.h h/tconst.h $(INCDIR)/libumps.e Makefile

CFLAGS = -ffreestanding -ansi -c -mips1 -mabi=32 -mfp32 -mno-gpopt -G 0 -fno-pic -mno-abicalls
# -Wall

LDAOUTFLAGS = -G 0 -nostdlib -T $(SUPDIR)/umpsaout.ldscript
LDCOREFLAGS =  -G 0 -nostdlib -T $(SUPDIR)/umpscore.ldscript

CC = mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc
LD = mipsel-linux-gnu-ld
AS = mipsel-linux-gnu-as -KPIC

EF = umps3-elf2umps
UDEV = umps3-mkdev

#main target
all: printerTest.umps strConcat.umps \
    fibEight.umps fibEleven.umps \
    terminalTest2.umps terminalTest3.umps terminalTest4.umps \
    terminalTest5.umps  \
    
%.o: %.c $(TDEFS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
    
%.t: %.o print.o  $(LIBDIR)/crti.o
    $(LD) $(LDAOUTFLAGS) $(LIBDIR)/crti.o $< print.o $(LIBDIR)/libumps.o -o $@
    
%.t.aout.umps: %.t
    $(EF) -a $<

%.umps: %.t.aout.umps
    $(UDEV) -f $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.t *.umps
```

Thanks to anyone who answers in advance :)

Comment: What happens when you try `make printerTest.o`? How about `make -v`?

Comment: `make -d` also prints _lots of_ debugging stuff.

Comment: @Beta `make -v`  prints the usual info about GNU make, nothing out of the ordinary, while `make printerTest.o` works normally... so I don't really know what's happening T.T

Comment: @thebusybee `make -d` prints A LOT of stuff. Though, the last few line are pretty interesting. It seems that it doesn't even look for `printerTest.c`, but I could be wrong.
Here's the full output https://pastebin.com/12nrezx2

Comment: Also, if I try to build `printerTest.umps`, it outputs make: `*** No rule to make target 'printerTest.umps'.  Stop.`, so...

Comment: It looks as if Make can neither find nor build `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/umps3/crti.o` (which it needs in order to build `printerTest.t`). Do you have such a file, or a source file for it?

Comment: @Beta that was exactly my problem.  `crti.o` was located in `/usr/lib/umps3/crti.o`, so I've corrected the path and now the makefile works. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, the problem was that the crti.o file was located on a particular hidden folder. Big thanks to the people who helped me in the comments :)